# FTDI FT232H not behaving as expected (not detected by Linux)

Tags: linux, opensuse

I have written an application using the FT232h with libftd2xx.so.1.4.24 for GPIO assess.  I had it running on two machines, a Linux openSUSE desktop and an openSUSE laptop. Both run the same kernel and both are Windows 10 boxes running VMware to give me the virtual  openSUSE machines. For some reason it suddenly stopped working on the desktop. I have been using the same FTDI FT232H device on both machines.

On the laptop, the FTDI chip is detected. dmesg | grep -i usb says:
usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6014, etc.
On the laptop, lsusb says:
Bus 002 Device 004” ID 0x0403:6014 Future Technology Devices International. Ltd: FT232H
Single HS USB-UART/FIFO IC

This information does not appear on the desktop. The desktop does not seem to detect the FT232H.

On the laptop I do sudo modprobe -r ftdi_sio usbserial and then perform an FT_Open(0, &fthandle) in libftd2xx.so.1.4.24.

On the desktop, ftdi_sio is not loaded. When I try to FT_Open(0, &fthandle) it fails with FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND. It dose the same thing when I run my app as root.

What do I need to do to get my desktop to run my app again? I haven’t blacklisted anything, to my knowledge.

I’m really stuck! Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

VMware may assign the USB to the host or to the guest. If the FT232H is plugged in but lsusb doesn't show the FT232H, then select VM -> Removable Devices -> Future Devices USB Serial Converter -> Connect (Disconnect from Host)
lsusb should now show the FT232H device and you should be able to invoke FT_Open on it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).